# Update some attributes in Coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, updates

Is CoreData has something like  :

```
update Table
set Field_1 = 0
where Field_2 = 10
```

To update several data at once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
NSArray *searchObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[searchObjects setValue:newValue forKey:@"entityProperty"];
[context save:&error];
```

you will have to create the `fetchRequest` object accordingly to your search criteria

Answer (score 0):

Step I : What you can do is, Fetch that particular record from Coredata using Predicate (Field_2) and keep that fetched record in the ManagedContext.

Step II : Change the values of fields in that context and follow the last step

Step III: save that managed object context.

Your change will be reflected in the coredata.

For code, you can use the code snippet option in Xcode and get the code snippet from there.

Comment: yeah, I know this method... may be there is something more short written )

Comment: @Romowski No shortcuts available as of now :)